# ACF/load_field not working for custom Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

On a custom post type (patient), I have a custom field which is another post object of type (room). It appears as just a drop down on the WP-admin and lists all the Rooms. I am trying to limit the rooms based on their categories, so only rooms in the category "vacant" will show up. Pretty straight forward.

Here is the code I am using

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=room', 'populateRooms');
function populateRooms($field)
{
    $field['choices'] = array();
    wp_reset_query();
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'room',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'room_category',
                'field'=>'slug',
                'terms' => 'vacant',
            )
        )
    ));
    $field['choices'] = array();
    foreach ($query->posts as $room_id => $matched_room) {
        $choices[$matched_room->ID] = $matched_room->post_title;
    }
    if (is_array($choices)) {
        foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
            $field['choices'][$key] = $choice;
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    return $field;
}
```

When I load the page, all rooms show up, including the ones not in the category "vacant", which is not what I want. When I echo out the $choices, I get this:

[image]

Which shows the post_ID -> post_title, as expected. However all rooms show up, not just these 3.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does it output if you do `var_dump($field['choices']);` right before the `return $field;`?

Comment: The image there, showing the array, thats the output. I said echo, but what I meant was ```echo '<pre>', print_r( $field['choices'], 1 ), '</pre>';```

Comment: But, since you asked: ```array(3) { [1295]=> string(5) "366-1" [1415]=> string(5) "438-4" [1251]=> string(5) "212-1" }```

Comment: That means your hook isn't working. Are you sure your field has name room in this add_filter('acf/load_field/name=room', 'populateRooms');

Comment: Well it has a field called Room, you can see the custom field setup in this image: https://i.imgur.com/xgdfeHi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is filter the search result of the field with `post_object/query` instead of using the `load_field` filter.

What you update seems to be for fields like checkboxes, selects, radio buttons and other fields with options.

```
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=room', function ($args, $field, $id) {
    $args['tax_query'] = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'room_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'vacant'
        ]
    ];

    return $args;
}, 10, 3);
```

For more information: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/

Comment: Maybe my approach was wrong, I will give this a try!

Comment: @Leathel Sure let me know how it goes :)

Comment: This answer worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Leathel No problem :)